# Select original column name as metadata from SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

I would like to select metadata from my SQL Server view. I can retrieve the views and column names through `sys.views` and `sys.columns`, for example with this code.

```
select schema_name(v.schema_id) as schema_name,
       object_name(c.object_id) as view_name,
       c.name as column_name
from sys.columns c
join sys.views v 
     on v.object_id = c.object_id
order by schema_name,
         view_name
```

However, I would also like to select the original column name from the source. In this case, `Column1` and `Column2` are the desired output from this view.

```
CREATE VIEW dim.person 
AS
    SELECT
        Column1 AS [Name],
        Column2 AS [Age]
    FROM
        dbo.person
```

Is there an easy way to get these values?

Comment: You can find the view definition in `sys.sql_modules`

Comment: `VIEW`s aren't always that simple (in fact, most of the time they aren't). A `VIEW` is effectively a pseudo table defined by a `SELECT`. Your object, `dim.person` is very simple, and it can easily be seen that `column1` is `name`. What, however, would you expect if you had `CONCAT_WS(' ',Column1,Column2) AS FullName`? What about if there was a CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER` partition on `Column4` and ordered by `Column5`? What about a conditional aggregate which returned different columns depending on the value of another?

Comment: If you mean you want to get original columns used from tables, you could use INFORMATION_SCHEMA..View_Table_USAGE and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.View_Column_USAGE. Also SQL definition itself is in VIEWS. As @Larnu pointed out however, you wouldn't be able to get "X column in View is C column in table T".

Comment: You ought to be able to resolve the original column names with the help of a [`TSqlParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-160). It won't be trivial. Nested views, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The metadata structure is there, but it only tracts which objects and columns are referenced by the view.  Not which view columns reference which source columns.

```
select referencing_minor_id, referenced_entity_name, referenced_minor_name
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dim.Person', 'OBJECT')
```

outputs

```
referencing_minor_id referenced_entity_name   referenced_minor_name
-------------------- ------------------------ -------------------------
0                    person                   NULL
0                    person                   Column1
0                    person                   Column2
```

The "referencing_minor_id" would be the column_id, but it's not populated.  So the only thing that's tracked is that `dim. Person` depends on Column1 and Column2 of `dbo.person`.

Comment: I should've been more specific about my data source. I'm querying a Data Lake through Azure Synapse Serverless SQL, meaning my data is stored in files. My example query was simplified to avoid confusion. A view could look like this
```CREATE VIEW [dim].[Location] AS
SELECT
    DataLoad_Location_join AS ID,
    Domestic_chain_c AS DomestiChain,
    Banner_c AS Banner
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK '/MASTER DATA/LOCATION/**',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'curatedzone',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) 
AS [r]```

Your solution with DMV unfortunately is not supported